# Resetting user password from hybrid ad desktop without azure writeback

Tags: active-directory, ldap, entra-id, write-back

Within an environment with a "local" ad setup with its on directly connected desktops as well as having an azure AD with a connection between the two ADs, password writeback is not to be enabled.

Within this environment there is also computers that Azure hybrid ad joined with only a VPN connection to the "local" AD's network for file server access etc. This would stop users of these devices from being able to reset their password as writeback is not enabled.

Is there a way to be able to reset user passwords in this setup? I've wondered if the built-in `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry`/`DirectorySearcher` classes as I've seen that you can "invoke" methods on DirectoryEntrys and `de.Invoke("setPassword", $pwd)` would seemingly set the password for the "de" which was retrieved by an LDAP path found using DirectorySearcher which seems to find AD attributes such as "memberOf" which is not found on the azure ad which leads me to believe that resetting a password this way would do so directly on the local AD working when the VPN to the local AD's network is active and would need to done from an account with permission to reset ad user passwords.